# Ambari Kerberos Wizard Trust ldaps subject alternative DNS name

Tags: hadoop, ssl, ssl-certificate, kerberos, ambari

I'm setting up kerberos with an existing Active Directory as KDC and having an issue communicating to the ldaps server. We have a cluster of servers for AD. let's say server1.example.com,server2.example.com,server3.example.com and the company just uses example.com to connect. I've setup ldap integration with amabri for user access to the portal via the ambari-server setup-ldap, but did it without ssl and I can use ldap://example.com as the ldap server and it works fine. With ldaps, however, ldaps://example.com:636 doesn't work. I get an error in the ambari-server.log: "java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching example.com found". I have imported the CA cert and each individual server's certificate into my keystore and put the ca in /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/activedirectory.pem, but I still can't get it to work for example.com. I can get it to work for server1.example.com and all the others individually, but I can't get it to work for the example.com dns name. I don't have control over the certificate creation on the AD ldaps side. These certs were self-signed by the AD server and each server has it's own certificate. Is there anyway to tell ambari to accept invalid certs for the kerberos wizard, or any other way to get the broader domain name to work? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you sure that `ldaps` is useful? I thought recent versions of AD always force TLS encryption on `ldap` -- check with your admins.

Comment: When using AD auth at OS level, with SSSD, you can specify a _list_ of LDAP servers... and another list as failover servers. Doesn't Ambari support that? Besides, from experience, the DNS alias may promote AD servers that are more relevant for user PCs than for servers in a Data Center (or worse, in a cloud) hence a different list may be beneficial.